# Creating a ZigBee Light Link Compatible Light

Tags: arduino, light, zigbee

I've seen lots of [talk](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196372/direct-zigbee-communication-with-philips-hue-smart-light-bulbs) [about](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49629/zigbee-light-link-and-xbee-interoperability) using arduino/pi/etc and a zigbee board to talk to existing ZigBee Light Link compatible lights such as the latest Phillips Hue bulbs. But I want to go the other way... I want to make the light but be able to use that with any existing ZigBee Light Link supported hub device (Samsung SmartThings, Wink, etc). But sadly, aside from the official ZLL spec doc, can't really find anything.  Maybe this just isn't done outside of large corporations? I'd really love to be able to just use, for example, and arduino compatible chip, ZigBee radio, and then appear to a home automation hub as a ZLL compatible light.

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing.. have you had any luck? I've ordered a couple of different hue compatible bulbs of aliexpress.. I noticed in the write up it talked about the IEEE 802.15.4 protocol. I'll keep you posted on how I get on. [Link to bulb](http://s.aliexpress.com/Zbq2ua6z). Also I found that the cc2530 seems to be a [development kit](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2530zdk-zll) for this kind of thing. There are cc2530 dev kits on aliexpress also.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with a [MeshBee](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Mesh_Bee/) or any other controller with an NXP JN516x chip. Read all the details here: [Custom Hue lights](https://peeveeone.com/?p=187)

Comment: The seeedstudio link is broken :(